Does ETH imply P vs NP is decidable?
I have been reading Scott Aaronson's summary paper on P vs NP. In this paper, there was a section about the likelihood of the problem being undecidable (page 28). He mentions a paper that I could no get my hands on by S. Ben-David and S. Halevi entitled "Independence of P versus NP." It is supposedly proven in this paper that if P!=NP is proven to be unprovable in some weaker theories ($\mathrm{PA} + \Pi_1$), then we would have almost P=NP (he says that NP problems must at least have an algorithm that runs in $n^{\log \log \log \log n}$).
My question is, does this imply that if ETH or SETH are true, then P vs NP is decidable for sure?

This doesn't sound like a research-level question and would be more suitable for CS.SE. Anyway, ETH says “SAT requires exponential time”, so ETH ⇒ P ≠ NP by definition.

@JeanAbouSamra: But it might be the case that SAT requires exponential time, but you can't prove it, so it's undecidable. The result is not trivial.

Oops, sorry for the stupid comment, I should get some rest.

I don't understand this question. Let's say undeidable means "not provable from ZFC". If ZFC |- ETH, then (probably) ZFC |- P not NP. But if ZFC does not prove ETH, then what does "ETH is true" even mean?

@ReijoJaakkola By ‘ETH is true’ one probably refers to the statement being true in the standard model of the theory/in the metatheory. Truth is different from provability.

"ETH is true" just means ETH.

@NoelArteche But if the theory/metatheory is ZFC (or something stronger), then what is its standard model?

http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shai/ph.ps.gz

FYI here is the Ben-David and Halevi paper: https://web.archive.org/web/20221224145635/http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/1991/CS/CS0699.revised.pdf

The edited question makes much more sense.

@JoshuaGrochow : Thanks for the link. I will see if I can find my answer in the paper. Although just by looking at the beginning, its not clear if the running time they mentioned applies to worst case.

The first point to be aware of about our PvsNP paper is that the direction
"If SAT can't be solved in 'almost polynomial' time then $\mathrm{P \neq NP}$ is provable" applies only to provability in a very strong system ($\mathrm{PA}+Π_1$). This is an undecidable proof system so it is not one wishes to design proofs in (there is no algorithm that can tell a valid proof from an invalid one).
Indeed, if ETH is true then our result implies that there will be a proof of $\mathrm{P \neq NP}$ in that strong proof system. The reason the result requires the strong proof system is that one needs a system that can prove the equivalence of any two Turing machines that compute the same function (otherwise a simple diagonalization trick can generate an undecidable statement equivalent to $\mathrm{P \neq NP}$). The collection of all such statements is equivalent to the $\Pi_1$ theory of natural numbers.

Thanks for the helpfull answer and even more helpfull paper !
